# Running untrusted code in google cloud build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm working on a new CI service (SaaS) and plan to use Google Cloud Build to actually execute the builds. The cloudbuild service account necessarily has to have access to all sorts of GCP services (storage buckets, datastore etc). But in one of the steps it also runs untrusted (ie. user-supplied) code. My question: is there a way to lock down individual steps inside a cloudbuild.yml recipe to not have access to GCP? Ideally that step would have access only to the filesystem and the public internet (to download external dependencies), but nothing else.

Comment: Interesting! I can think of 2 ways to solve this OTOMH: First, "limitedStep" instead of "step" that is limited in some static way (no GCP service calls); Second, a more general solution of providing a service account (if not default) for the step to be run-as. You could then provide this account with constrained (alternative) credentials to steps of your choosing. Would either help?

Comment: The second solution is a generalisation of the first one: by providing a service account which has no roles attached you effectively deny access to any GCP service calls, right? Though from a usability perspective it would be nice to offer both, eg. in cloudbuild.yaml step definition set `serviceAccount: false` to disable access to GCP completely and `serviceAccount: some-account-123@gserviceaccount.com` to explicitly set a different service account.

Comment: Correct! In fact, I propose that each step can be provided its own service account and each service account would have its own set of roles (including your requirement of not having access to GCP services). I was unable to find a public issue track for Cloud Build. I'm going to talk to PM and file a FR for you. I'll report back. My account's the same here @google.com